# inverting image in Python with OpenCV

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, image-processing

I want to load a color image, convert it to grayscale, and then invert the data in the file.

What I need: to iterate over the array in OpenCV and change every single value with this formula (it might be wrong but it seems reasonable for me):

```
img[x,y] = abs(img[x,y] - 255)
```

but I don't understand why doesn't it works:

```
def inverte(imagem, name):
    imagem = abs(imagem - 255)
    cv2.imwrite(name, imagem)


def inverte2(imagem, name):
    for x in np.nditer(imagem, op_flags=['readwrite']):
        x = abs(x - 255)
    cv2.imwrite(name, imagem)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nome = str(sys.argv[1])
    image = cv2.imread(nome)
    gs_imagem = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    inverte(gs_imagem, "invertida.png")
    inverte2(gs_imagem, "invertida2.png")
```

I don't want to do an explicit loop (I am trying to be more pythonic). I can see that in one image that got a white background it turned black, but only this it doesn't looks like the other colors are having much (if any) change.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

You almost did it. You were tricked by the fact that `abs(imagem-255)` will give a wrong result since your `dtype` is an unsigned integer. You have to do `(255-imagem)` in order to keep the integers unsigned:

```
def inverte(imagem, name):
    imagem = (255-imagem)
    cv2.imwrite(name, imagem)
```

You can also invert the image using the `bitwise_not` function of OpenCV:

```
imagem = cv2.bitwise_not(imagem)
```

Answer (score 85):

Alternatively, you could invert the image using the `bitwise_not` function of OpenCV:

```
imagem = cv2.bitwise_not(imagem)
```

I liked [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/filling-holes-in-an-image-using-opencv-python-c/) example.

Answer (score 43):

You can use "tilde" operator to do it:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("img.png")
image = ~image
cv2.imwrite("img_inv.png",image)
```

This is because the "tilde" operator (also known as unary operator) works doing a complement dependent on the type of object

for example for integers, its formula is:

x + (~x) = -1

but in this case, opencv use an "uint8 numpy array object" for its images so its range is from 0 to 255

so if we apply this operator to an "uint8 numpy array object" like this:

```
import numpy as np
x1 = np.array([25,255,10], np.uint8) #for example
x2 = ~x1
print (x2)
```

we will have as a result:

```
[230 0 245]
```

because its formula is:

x2 =  255 - x1

and that is exactly what we want to do to solve the problem.

Comment: I think your answer would be better if you explained a bit why this works.

Comment: "255" should replace "256" in  "x2 = 256 - x1".

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it with numpy.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('your_image', 0)
inverted = np.invert(image)

cv2.imwrite('inverted.jpg', inverted)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python/OpenCV, I think you want:

```
img = cv2.absDiff(img, 255)
```

Comment: another clever option

Comment: AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'absDiff'

Comment: It is cv2.absdiff().  Sorry about the misspelling. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga6fef31bc8c4071cbc114a758a2b79c14

Answer (score 0):

Why not use *the first line in the question* with `numpy`?

```
inverted = np.abs(image - 255)
```

Just as simple as that. No iteration or any other function needed. `numpy` does that automatically for us :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    def invert(self, image=None):
        if image is None:
            image = self.image

        image = image.astype("uint8") # --> pay attention to the image type
        inverted = np.invert(image)
        (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(inverted, 0, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
        return im_bw
```