# bounded sum or difference of arrays in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to add or subtract two arrays in numpy but the result has to be bounded for each element. If I restrict the typ (i.e. uint8) any exeeding sum produces an overflow (i.e. start from zero again) and any exeeding difference an underflow (i.e. start from 255 again). This is not what I want, i.e. I want to stop at 0/255 (in my example).

Is there any way to do this without accessing each element?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This is a similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19580102/832621) that may help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a mask

Example: addition not exceeding 255:

```
import numpy as np
# create exaple data where sum exceeds 255
a = np.arange(118,130,dtype = np.uint8)
b = a.copy()
res = np.add(a,b, dtype = np.uint16);
mask = res > 255
res[mask] = 255
res = np.uint8(res)
```

Results are:

```
>>> print a
array([118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129], dtype=uint8)
>>> print b
array([118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129], dtype=uint8)
>>> print mask
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True], dtype=bool)
>>> print res
array([236, 238, 240, 242, 244, 246, 248, 250, 252, 254, 255, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

The mask only works correct as a numpy array. Otherwise, advanced indexing will return a view, not a copy, see [SciPy/NumPy documentation.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: Is this also working, if the np.type is uint8? I checked it and the answer is no. So I need to convert the arrays to a larger type (how?) prior to adding it?

Comment: See my edit. Now, `a`, `b` and result `res` are np.uint8

Comment: Where can I accept it? THere is no button to click on, is it?

Comment: Below the voting symbol left of the answer, there's a check mark. When you hover it with the mouse it should ask whether you want to accept it. See a description [here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
Accepting the answer also shows other users that a solution exists for the given problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63933/discussion-between-jkalden-and-michael-hecht).

Comment: I thik that it's better using the `np.int16` data type to support also the difference case

Comment: @Aelius: might also work, or maybe even better, but my answer is also more than 6 years old, so I just leave it as is...

Comment: yes, I wrote a comment only for reference of further readers

Answer (score 1):

You can work with OpenCV if you have the cv2 library :

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np  

x=np.uint8([250])  
y=np.uint8([10])  
print cv2.add(x,y)  #250+ 10 =260=>255
```

Answer :

```
[[255]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by jkalden, it's possible to use the [add](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) and [subtract](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html) function of NumPy with a [`dtype`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html)range wider than the `uint8` data type, but instead of passing through a mask you can use the [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function:

```
a = np.arange(118,130,dtype = np.uint8)
b = a.copy()
sum = np.add(a,b, dtype = np.int16)
uint8_sum = np.where(sum>255, 255, sum).astype(np.uint8)
```

Result:

```
>>> print(uint8_sum)
array([236, 238, 240, 242, 244, 246, 248, 250, 252, 254, 255, 255],
  dtype=uint8)
```

In the same way it's possible to perform the subtraction:

```
a = np.arange(118,130,dtype = np.uint8)
b = a.copy()[::-1]
diff = np.subtract(a,b, dtype = np.int16)
uint8_diff = np.where(diff<0, 0, diff).astype(np.uint8)
```

Result:

```
>>> print(uint8_diff)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11],
  dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

simplified one-liners using *np.where* as suggested by Aelius, without extra variable and extra type convertions

**Bounded add:**

```
summ = np.where(np.add(a,b, dtype = np.int16)>255,255,a+b)
```

**Bounded subtract:**

```
subb = np.where(np.subtract(a,b, dtype = np.int16)<0,0,a-b)
```

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(118,135,dtype = np.uint8)
b = a.copy()

summ = np.where(np.add(a,b, dtype = np.int16)>255,255,a+b)
>>> print(summ)
[236 238 240 242 244 246 248 250 252 254 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]

subb = np.where(np.subtract(a,b[::-1], dtype = np.int16)<0,0,a-b[::-1])
>>> print(subb)
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16]
```