# detecting contours in image with white background

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am having trouble detecting contours in this image

Class Diagram Image

[image]

I want to detect all border contours in the diagram but so far my program is only detecting the image border as shown in this image

[image]

Ignore the 0 in the center that is just to show that it is contour 0.

I am not sure where the problem lies in my code as it can detect contours in images with a black background.

```
filename = sys.argv[1]
t = int(sys.argv[2])
img = cv2.imread(filename)

resized = imutils.resize(img, width=300)
ratio = img.shape[0] / float(resized.shape[0])

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
(t, binary) = cv2.threshold(blur, t, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

_ ,cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for (i,c) in enumerate(cnts):
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    if M["m00"] != 0:
        cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    else:
        cX, cY = 0, 0
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),(0, 255, 255), 2)
    print("Object %d has dimensions x=%d, y=%d, w=%d, h=%d area=%d" % (i,x,y,w,h,int(w*h)))
    cv2.putText(img, str(i), (cX, cY),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am note sure where the problem lies in my code as it can detect contours in images with a black background.

This is almost definitly your problem. From the [OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

> In OpenCV, finding contours is like finding white object from black background. So remember, object to be found should be white and background should be black.

[This SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580102/inverting-image-in-python-with-opencv) shows you how to invert your image.

You definitely need to be detecting white on black, as discussed [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/2885/findcontours-gives-me-the-border-of-the-image/)

Comment: that's sorted it! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @NicholasMilner Great, please upvote and accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to invert your image, you can use cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV instead.

```
(t, binary) = cv2.threshold(blur, t, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```