# How can I convert normal image to X ray image in python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

My goal is to convert normal image to X ray image using Python(OpenCV, numpy, Pillow), I've done some part of it, I've modified the image a little bit but I can't make it X ray.

I've tried mutiple ways to do this specific task but It doesn't go the way I want [My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbBEa.jpg), and this is what I expect to see [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPW1z.jpg)

and here is my code so far.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

def apply_xray_effect(input_image_path, output_image_path):
    # Read the input image using Pillow (PIL)
    pil_image = Image.open(input_image_path)

    # Convert PIL image to NumPy array
    img_np = np.array(pil_image)

    # Apply a custom transformation to simulate X-ray effect
    # You can customize this transformation to achieve the desired effect
    xray_effect = img_np.copy()

    # Apply brightness and contrast adjustments
    alpha = 0.3  # Adjust contrast (1.0 is the original contrast)
    beta = -140  # Adjust brightness (0 is the original brightness)
    xray_effect = cv2.convertScaleAbs(xray_effect, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)

    # Apply a pseudo-color map to give it a blueish tone
    colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(xray_effect, cv2.COLORMAP_BONE)

    x = 200  # X-coordinate of the top-left corner of the ROI
    y = 250  # Y-coordinate of the top-left corner of the ROI
    width = 300  # Width of the ROI
    height = 250  # Height of the ROI

    # Convert PIL image to NumPy array
    pil_image_np = np.array(pil_image)

    # Create a mask for the ROI
    mask = np.zeros_like(pil_image_np)
    cv2.rectangle(mask, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), (255, 255, 255), thickness=-1)  # Fill the ROI with white

    # Apply the mask to the image to extract the ROI
    roi = cv2.bitwise_and(pil_image_np, mask)

    # Change the color of the ROI (e.g., from blue to green)
    roi[:, :, 0] = 0  # Set the blue channel to 0 (remove blue)
    roi[:, :, 1] = 0  # Set the green channel to 255 (max green)
    roi[:, :, 2] = 0  # Set the red channel to 0 (remove red)

    # Save the resulting X-ray-like image
    cv2.imwrite(output_image_path, colormap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_image_path = r"C:\Users\Ayad\OneDrive\Desktop\girl.jpeg"  # Replace with your input image file path
    output_directory = r"C:\Users\Ayad\OneDrive\Desktop"  # Output directory path

    output_xray_image_path = os.path.join(output_directory, "changedImg_xray.png")

    apply_xray_effect(input_image_path, output_xray_image_path)

    # Display the images
    xray_image = cv2.imread(output_xray_image_path)

    cv2.imshow("X-ray Image", xray_image)

    cv2.waitKey(0)  # Wait until a key is pressed to close the windows
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please provide the input image!  You will need to create a custom colormap.

Comment: Even a custom color map may not handle the situation. X-ray image intensities are not linear in a one-to-one fashion with normal images. Some regions that are bright in a normal image may need to be dark in the X-ray and vice-versa.

Comment: You make an x-ray image using x-ray wavelength radiation. Your image was made using visible wavelengths. These are fundamentally different. It’s like saying you have a boat and you want to make it into an airplane. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

One step in making your example image appear closer to the xray example, would be to invert it. This would, for example, make the gaps between the teeth black, instead of white. You can implement this by adding `xray_effect = ~xray_effect` here:

```
xray_effect = cv2.convertScaleAbs(xray_effect, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)

# Invert the image such that negative space is black
xray_effect = ~xray_effect

# Apply a pseudo-color map to give it a blueish tone
colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(xray_effect, cv2.COLORMAP_BONE)
```

More ways of inverting images are [mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580102/inverting-image-in-python-with-opencv)

As noted by other commenters, you cannot convert a normal image to x-ray. I'm assuming you just want the aesthetical 'xray effect', like a filter.